# More instances of fragment at one time - resources referencing to wrong views in android

Tags: android, view, resources, instance, fragment

this is a though one for me. I have a MainActiviy which extends FragmentAnctivity. There I have 1 FrameLayout and buttons below to change frame's content. I do so by switching show/hide for created fragments which I added to FrameLayout before in OnCreate.

I'm also nesting more fragments in 1 fragment (As I have 1 fragment for 1 type of content and inside of it there is listFragment which is changed to DetailFragment after OnItemClick... again with show/hide approach).

Problem is that in 2 different contents I have 2 different instances of 1 Fragment class, so those 2 instances use 1 same layout file. And although the first of those fragment is hidden and 2nd is shown, when I change some view through 2nd instance then layout of 1st instance is changed and 2nd remains same as before. (Hope it is understandable)

I guess it's totally a mistake in managing and understanding of fragments' lifecycle, so can please someone help me to solve this?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you get main point of fragments using practices. Your problem is simple. I almost sure you use `getActivity().findViewById(...)` calls to access views in your `Fragment` (or nested `Fragment` whatever). I this case Activity would return you fist view with defined id from whole your views hierarchy.

Solution is pretty simple - you just must avoid `getActivity().findViewById(...)` construction  and get all links to views in `onCreateView()` callback and use exact **this** link with all future operations. Than everything will be ok. Here is  simple example:

```
 private TextView mDummyText;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name, container, false);
    initMembersViews(v);
    return v;
}

private void initMembersViews(View v) {
    mDummyText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fr_houses_list_text);
}
```

Hope it would helps you! Good luck!